What is the closed form of the indefinite integral of $(a - x)^n$ with respect to $x$?
A professor evaluated the following integral as follows
$$\int{(a-x)^3 dx} = -\frac{1}{4}(a-x)^4.$$ And I've seen this generalization online as well but when is it true? It doesn't hold for $n=1$ obviously and intuitively I would say that it's never true. Since by using it we always get a larger exponent in $a$ than usual:
$$\int{(a-x)dx} = ax - \frac{1}{2}x^2 \neq -\frac{1}{2}(a-x)^2.$$
If it's only true for definite integrals what is the theorem precisely?
Have I made an error in my reasoning?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. You need a $+C$. They're picking the antiderivative that vanishes at $x=a$; you're picking the one that vanishes at $x=0$.

$\color{red}C=-\frac12a^2$

It seems like this would be a good point in your classwork to talk directly to your teacher.

You do know that antiderivatives are all equivalent up to a constant term?
What your teacher used is a form of $u$-substitution, which (fun fact) in Russia is commonly known as getting under the differential sign. Since $\mathbb{d}(x-a)$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{d}x$ when $a$ is a constant, you may use that fact to perform the following chain of thought:
$$
\int (a-x)^{n} \, \mathbb{d}x = -\int (a-x)^{n} \, \mathbb{d}(a-x) = \\
=
\Bigg|
\begin{array}{rl}
u&=&a-x \\
\mathbb{d}u&=&\mathbb{d}(a-x)=-\mathbb{d}x
\end{array}
\Bigg|
= \\
= -\int u^{n} \, \mathbb{d}u = -\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} + C = = -\frac{(a-x)^{n+1}}{n+1} + C
$$
Notice how in your case the missing term is just a constant, which is irrelevant with antiderivatives and cancels out when taking definite integrals.

Thank you very much! I actually realised this later in the dad but couldn't get to answering the question myself. I was initially confused since this wasn't a math course and the expression came up in another form as a part of a set of calculations.
